# Git hook command has seriously messed with my directory listings

Tags: sh

Got this line of code in `.git/hooks/post-checkout`:

`exec vim +PackerCompile +"sleep 100m" +qall`

The vim command ran fine from the command line. But apparently, not so well in `sh`.

When I switch to a branch, I get a very messy output:

```
Switched to branch 'clean'
                          Your branch is up to date with 'origin/clean'.
                                                                        Vim: Warning: Input is not from a terminal
```

Even worse, my directory listings are all screwy:

```
> $ ls -la                                                                                                            [±clean ✓]
total 4
       drwxr-xr-x  6 user staff 192 Feb 26 20:59 .
                                                          drwxr-xr-x  5 user staff 160 Feb 26 16:39 ..
                                                                                                              drwxr-xr-x  3 user staff  96 Feb 26 16:55 .compiled_packer_config
                                                      drwxr-xr-x  5 user staff 160 Feb 26 20:59 lua
                                                                                                           drwxr-xr-x 19 user staff 608 Feb 20 16:56 templates
                                     -rw-r--r--  1 user staff 279 Feb 26 20:59 init.lua
```

It looks like I've got some whitespace characters in there. These whitespace characters are showing up in all directories in this terminal. In other terminals, things display normally. But WTF happened? And how do I fix?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I stuck with what I'm more familiar with and used bash. Works just fine:

```
#!/bin/zsh

#exec git update-server-info
bash -c '/usr/local/bin/nvim +PackerCompile +"sleep 100m" +qall'
```